# Why don't we add a semicolon (;) at the end of if/else?

Tags: if-statement, syntax, rust, expression

In Rust, I have noticed that everything is an expression except 2 kinds of statements. Every expression that adds `;` will become a statement. Rust's grammar wants statements to follow other statements.

So why don't we add `;` at the end of an `if` / `else` "expression"?  This is also an expression, so why don't we do this:

```
if true {
    println!("true");
} else {
    println!("false");
};
```

Comment: I don't know if you are going to get any clear, concise answers to *why* Rust allows this. It could just be "because it looks better" or "that's the way other similar languages do it". For what it's worth, you *can* put the `;` there, and I have when I use `if` / `else` as a ternary statement on one line.

Comment: The semicolon can be omitted after an `if`, `while` or `match` expression if that expression is the "root" expression of a statement.

Comment: Discussed extensively on reddit http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2qjvzr/why_ifelse_expression_in_rust_doesnt_end_with_a/

Comment: @dbaupp the reddit post is mine. After I post my question in here and seems very little people pay attention to it. In fact, if you give more and more experiment with my question, you will find it's very confusing than the "look" it should be.

Comment: I am not sure why this question received downvotes and 4 closing votes. It is a very good question, and the answer on reddit is very nice and interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The most common answer in the [discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2qjvzr/why_ifelse_expression_in_rust_doesnt_end_with_a/) is that it looks more like what users coming from other languages expect, and there is no harm in allowing that syntax (since the result type is `()` thanks to semicolons in the branches).

Answer (score 1):

I guess because it is a block expression in other languages like Java or Nginx-Conf a semicolon is only set after statements and not after blocks.